# Symfony 3/Composer: how to install a project correctly?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've checked out a **Symfony 3** project and tried to **install the dependencies** via `php composer.phar install`, but it **breaks** on `cache:clear --no-warmup`, because the **dependencies are already used** in the `AppKernel.php`.

After commenting these lines, the installation broke because of the dependencies already used in the `config.yml`.

I don't think an installation should take more than 2 minutes and I'm doing it wrong.

Is there any **command that installs all the dependencies without checking** if they are already used **?**

Edit: that's the error message:

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                    
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                             


  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Class 'FOS\JsRoutingBundle  
  \FOSJsRoutingBundle' not found in /usr/www/users/app/app/AppKernel.php:28               
  Stack trace:                                                                                                          
  #0 /usr/www/users/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.p  
  hp(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()                                                                                 
  #1 /usr/www/users/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.p  
  hp(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                                                     
  #2 /usr/www/users/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Consol  
  e/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                                                    
  #3 /usr/www/users/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application  
  .php(117): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInpu  
  t), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOu in /usr/www/users/app/app/AppKer  
  nel.php on line 28
```

Edit 2: result of `php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle`

```
Using version ^2.1 for friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

Comment: What does the actual error say?

Comment: Put everything back the way it was then delete the var/cache directory and try bin/console again.  This assumes that the project was working and that you have the min php version installed.

Comment: @hcoat Error message added, please have a look. Thx!

Comment: @Cerad I deleted the `var/cache`, but it didn't work. The project works fine on my initial installation. I'm able to clone it from git, but can't install the dependencies. Please have a look at the added error message. Thx!

Comment: The error message implies that the FOSJsRoutingBundle never got installed.  Possibly a version issue.  You can try running "composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle" and see what errors you get.  Lot of these bundles are not maintained very well.

Comment: @Cerad Good to know, thx. I added the response. The `Killed` doesn't look good to me.

Comment: `Killed` usually means that you ran out of memory.

Comment: Yep. Memory issue.  I sometimes get this when using a small virtual machine.  You might try a reboot to clear up some memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I should have enough memory, but I quickly "solved" the issue by uploading the vendor files manually.